# "He fell off the horse" OR "He fell from the horse"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> He fell from/off the horse and broke his arm

I'm in doubt. Which version sounds more natural in English?

Comment: We don't do editing here and you need to show some research. Also, this question belongs on ELL and not here. Thanks. :) Some mod should migrate the question to ELL.

Comment: I think it should have stayed where it was - it would never have occurred to me there was a significant usage split based on first/third person subject, but *no* significant difference between AmE / BrE, despite the fact that Americans are culturally still far more interested in horse-riding than Brits. It can only be a formal / informal thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This question is a baby question which is why I think it needed to be here and not there.

Comment: The question probably should have been left on ELU until the specific problem OP was asking about was clarified. Is this about prepositions or verbs? (It would be harder to justify keeping it on ELU if it's about the verbs.)

Comment: @Laurel: I never even *noticed* the verb switch until after it was migrated. Migrated *while* I was composing my answer to the Q on ELU, so I was actually *glad* to discover that it had been migrated, since any other reasons why I couldn't post my answer would probably have implied I might as well throw the answer away for lack of anywhere to put it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Considering that you already wrote an answer about prepositions, I've edited the question to be about that. If everlearner2023 does want to know about the verbs, that should be asked as a new question (on ELL).

Comment: @Laurel How does a  preposition or verb question make it good for ELU?

Comment: @Lambie I'm only talking about these specific questions. FF pointed out a difference in preposition usage that even native speakers probably don't know about. I don't think there's any such complexity to the difference between the verbs. The difference between the verbs is also readily available online—just apparently not in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Both prepositions are fine - they mean the same, and there's no significant AmE / BrE usage split. *But* there is a tale to be told [using NGrams...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fell%20from%20his%20horse%2Cfell%20off%20his%20horse%2C%28%28fell%20from%20my%20horse%29%20*%208%29%2C%28%28fell%20off%20my%20horse%29%20*%208%29&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]

Note that I increased occurrence counts for *fell off/from **my** horse* by a factor of 8 so they could be compared with the far more common *fell off/from **his** horse*, because we're only interested in the relative frequency of the two different prepositions. The fact that ***his*** horse is more common in absolute terms is distractingly irrelevant.

There will be hundreds if not *thousands* of written instances of all four variants, so I'm confident it's statistically significant that ***I** fell **off my** horse* and ***He** fell **from his** horse* are much more common than the other way around.

The obvious reason for the difference is that such utterances are more likely to be ***informal*** in first person (me), and ***formal*** in third person (him).